# Update javascript object conditionally

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular component, I am defining a Javascript object such as

```
myObj = {
        "option": ["valid"],
        "cities": [
          "London",
          "Paris",
          "Rome"
        ],
        "routes": [{
          "section": 'option1',
          "class": true
        }],
        "def": [
          {
            "name": "name1",
            "attributes": [
              "test"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

Now based on a condition, I want to either include or exclude the 'routes' section.

So, currently I am doing like this

```
if(somecondition) {
   myObj = {
        "option": ["valid"],
        "cities": [
          "London",
          "Paris",
          "Rome"
        ],
        "routes": [{
          "section": 'option1',
          "class": true
        }],
        "def": [
          {
            "name": "name1",
            "attributes": [
              "test"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
} else {
   myObj = {
        "option": ["valid"],
        "cities": [
          "London",
          "Paris",
          "Rome"
        ],
        "def": [
          {
            "name": "name1",
            "attributes": [
              "test"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

Wanted to check if there is a better way to achieve this as this is duplication of code and as the conditions increase this would no longer be maintainable.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
myObj = {
        "option": ["valid"],
        "cities": [
          "London",
          "Paris",
          "Rome"
        ],
        "def": [
          {
            "name": "name1",
            "attributes": [
              "test"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }

if(somecondition) {
   myObj.routes = [{
          "section": 'option1',
          "class": true
        }]
}
```

Define the object before and add the `routes` based on the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete a property of an object that way :

```
delete myObj.routes;
```

or

```
delete myObj['routes'];
```

Is that what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. Here if condition is not satisfied you can simply remove routes from object. Hope it help!

```
 myObj = {
            "option": ["valid"],
            "cities": [
              "London",
              "Paris",
              "Rome"
            ],
            "routes": [{
              "section": 'option1',
              "class": true
            }],
            "def": [
              {
                "name": "name1",
                "attributes": [
                  "test"
                ]
              }
            ]
          };

        if(!somecondition) {
          delete myObj.routes;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

By simply adding the `routes` property later based on your condition

```
myObj = {
  "option": ["valid"],
  "cities": [
    "London",
    "Paris",
    "Rome"
  ],
  "def": [{
    "name": "name1",
    "attributes": [
      "test"
    ]
  }]
};

if(somecondition) {
   myObj.routes = [{
       "section": 'option1',
       "class": true
   }];
}
```